# Deploying Maven project to JBoss AS7 (standalone)

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

I am new to JBOSS AS7, and am strictly using MAVEN 3 via command line. I would like to deploy the *.war of my project to JBOSS AS7 without ECLIPSE. I have spent couple of days Googling and trying out difference approaches. I am able to deploy the *.war to Tomcat. I would highly appreciate any help on this. So far this is what I have done:

I have entered the server info(Jboss) to C:\maven\conf\settings.xml 
I have included the plugin to the POM 
I think I may be declaring the path to JBoss AS7 within my JBOSS plugin wrong.

This is how I am including the plugin in the POM file:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
                      <configuration>
                          <url>http://localhost:8080/
                          <server>jboss</server>
                          <path>/web-app</path>
                      <configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have a look at the **README on the corresponding GitHub page**:
https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin

When deploying to your localhost (which is the default value) you don't need to define the `<url>` in the `<configuration>`, as well as the `<server>` and `<path>` elements (besides: I haven't seen a folder named wep-app in AS7).

We run a project where this works even **without** touching the `settings.xml`.

So when you have checked this, post what exactly goes wrong, what is the concrete **failure message** and what is the **maven command** you use (**mvn jboss-as:deploy**).

Comment: ,I cannot thank you enough for your help. I had no knowledge of README at all. I have never used JBOSS, and it is the first time I am employing it. I am now able to deploy the *.war.   Thanks you

Comment: Nice to see that it works for you. You might want to accept the answer as the right one.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. My Project is working in tomcat but its not working on Jboss 7.1.1 Final. Can you guide me steps what you are following. I just making a war file from eclipse through maven build and putting it in deployment folder.Its giving me error there.

Comment: @s.singh I think you should post a new stackoverflow question with detailed information on what you want to do, what you tried and what exactly goes wrong (stacktrace and so on). Also have a look at the official jboss documentation.